mysql build error on Raspberry Pi Model 3A+ with Raspbian
I am building MySQL version 8.0.37 on a Raspberry Pi Model 3A+ with the Raspbian OS.
I have encountered several build errors regarding missing dependancies and resolved them. I am now faced with an error I am not sure how to debug. Can anyone provide any insight ?
The error is:
In file included from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/log0recv.h:40,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/fil0fil.h:41,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/buf0buf.h:38,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/buf/checksum.cc:37:
/srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/log0sys.h:202:60: error: static assertion failed
  202 |  static_assert(decltype(write_to_file_requests_interval)::is_always_lock_free);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/buf/checksum.cc:37:
/srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/buf0buf.h:1742:42: error: static assertion failed
 1742 |     static_assert(decltype(prefix_info)::is_always_lock_free);
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/log0recv.h:40,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/fil0fil.h:41,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/buf0buf.h:38,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/dict0mem.h:63,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/dict0dict.h:45,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/dict/dict.cc:41:
/srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/log0sys.h:202:60: error: static assertion failed
  202 |   static_assert(decltype(write_to_file_requests_interval)::is_always_lock_free);
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/dict0mem.h:63,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/dict0dict.h:45,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/dict/dict.cc:41:
/srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/buf0buf.h:1742:42: error: static assertion failed
 1742 |     static_assert(decltype(prefix_info)::is_always_lock_free);
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/dict0dict.h:45,
                 from /srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/dict/dict.cc:41:
/srv/mysql-8.0.37/storage/innobase/include/dict0mem.h:2412:40: error: static assertion failed
 2412 |   static_assert(decltype(update_time)::is_always_lock_free);
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [storage/innobase/CMakeFiles/innodb_zipdecompress.dir/build.make:95: storage/innobase/CMakeFiles/innodb_zipdecompress.dir/buf/checksum.cc.o] Error 1

This doesn't look like a dependancy issue, but aside from that, I'm not sure how to interpret the error.
Background info
Raspbian is a fork of Debian, currently version 'bookworm'. The Raspbian Pi 3A+ has an ARMv8 processor with a 64-bit timer.
